# How can I remove a bugged block from my minecraft map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

We have a server running the Direwolf20 mod pack. We have encountered a problem with the TrainCraft mod. The seat to a zeppelin is stuck up in the air in the place of an old tower. Is there anyway to get rid of that? The block is unbreakable in the game even in creative mode. Its glitched out.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried stopping and starting the server? I know it may be inconvenient but it will most likely get rid of it because it may not actually be recognized as an entity that is there, it may just be a glitch. That is my theory anyway...

Comment: yeah we have rebooted it many times to change things and each time the block is still present in the same place.

Comment: If you have world edit, try the `//remove` command. Don't know how it goes exactly, but i'm sure you can find it somewhere.

Comment: Try getting a constant updating block next to it. The easiest way i can think of is to get a flow of water to flow over the block. This causes any block it crosses to update.

Comment: It's probably not a block per-se if it's the seat for a zepplin. It's more likely an entity that only ever listened directly to the zepplin mod code, so will probably not update itself when adjacent blocks change. You may have to use MCedit or WorldEdit to clear the space.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of MCedit or Worldedit, but was not sure if its safe to use on a SMP map.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a plugin/mod/program such as [WorldEdit](https://www.google.com/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-mods/worldedit/&q=&esrc=s&ei=zxu5UcqMOLPG0gGB9oCoBg&usg=AFQjCNFq9JHL0K-oGtAR7fmR9naq2Y0zNQ) or [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to try to edit it out of the world. If this fails, you can try Marco Geertsma's idea, which is to "get a flow of water to flow over the block."

If this doesn't work, I would uninstall the mod, play the map, then reinstall the mod. Your modded items might be gone, so use this as a "last resort."

Answer (score 1):

there are different things you can do: try using the debug menu. The combination F3+A for example reloads all chunks. If any debug doesn't help, try finding out what type of item this seat is. Is it an actual block, or something loose like an item frame? If the latter is the case, using the command /kill @e will kill everyone in the server, so you will lose xp, but it also removes minecarts, rails, item frames, etcetera. It might help as a last resort. You could also try to use `/setblock [coördinates of bugged block] minecraft:air 0 replace`this works better but requires cheating. it will turn this block into air. If this doesn't work, there are millions of other ways to remove blocks, try some. Any of these things, especially the last one, always helped for me in case of bugged blocks, try them out!